# Bash Concatenate and Replace carriage returns with newline

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to convert a series of text files that are formatted with line breaks to single lines separated by newlines (\n). For example:

```
This is an example text file 
where the contents are separated 
by line breaks
```

What I want this to look like is:

```
This is an example text file\nwhere the contents are separated\nby line breaks\n
```

I'm open to using awk, sed, or any builtin POSIX commands.

Comment: You mean `tr '\r' '\n' < file`

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n";ORS="\\n"}1' file.txt
```

What we are doing is detect the Record Separator like '\n', and when we print we use '\n', the double slash implies it must print '\n', to force the printing we use the pattern 1 with the default action (print the whole record).

If you have any problem let me know, I don't have an awk available to try it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear when you say "line break" if you you mean Carriage Return, Line Feed, or Newline or something else, nor is it clear if you want to replace newlines with the string `\n` or if you just want to strip Carriage Returns from newlines or something else, but if its the latter then all you need is:

```
dos2unix file
```

If you don't have dos2unix you can do it with any awk:

```
$ printf 'foo\r\nbar\r\n' | cat -v
foo^M
bar^M

$ printf 'foo\r\nbar\r\n' | awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")}1' | cat -v
foo
bar
```

You can't do it robustly with `tr` since it can't tell when a `\r` is at the end of a line or not, and you can't do it portably with `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/\n/\\n/g' file
```

Slurp the file into memory and quote newlines.